# Riemannian metric from metric

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a [manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold) (finite dimension) and a $d:M\times M\mapsto \mathbb{R}^+$ [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)) on $M$.

Does this define a Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$? Is it possible to derive **a metric tensor $g$ from the metric $d$**?

I don't care about the pathologies, let's say that you have geodesic completeness or any kind of regularities you want on $M$ and $d$.

Just for motivational background: it is well known how to get a metric on a Riemannian manifold. My question is the other way around.

Comment: I feel there are some metric $d$ can't induce a metric tensor . For example, $d(x,x)=0, d(x,y)=1 ,\forall x\in M, \forall y\ne x$.

Comment: You might look into metric derivatives https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_derivative.
This does not give you directly the metric tensor, but gives you a derivative of functions and in particular lets you define tangent spaces